# Connect MetaMask with Ganache

Tags: solidity, truffle, blockchain, metamask, ganache

unable to connect MetaMask with local blockchain(Ganache)

**Chrome Console Error**

> truffle-contract.js:425 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Contract has not been deployed to detected network (network/artifact mismatch)

*contract runs fine in truffle console*

```
web3.eth.getAccounts() // worked fine
```

**1_initial_migration.js**

```
var Election = artifacts.require("./Election.sol");


module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Election);
};
```

**2_deploy_migration.js**

```
var Election = artifacts.require("./Election.sol");


module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Election);
};
```

**truffle-config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
       host: "127.0.0.1",
       port: 7545,
       network_id: "*" // Match any network id
    },
    develop: {
       port: 8545
    }
  }
};
```

**App.js**

```
//Some code up here


initWeb3: function() {                             //Connect Client Side to locak blockchain
// TODO: refactor conditional
if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
  // If a web3 instance is already provided by Meta Mask.
  App.web3Provider = web3.currentProvider;
  web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
} else {
  // Specify default instance if no web3 instance provided
  App.web3Provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:7545');
  web3 = new Web3(App.web3Provider);
}
return App.initContract();
},


 //Some  more code here which contain contract deploying index.html file code
```

**On Ganache**

1. Network Id 5777
2. RPC Server http://127.0.0.1:7545

**MetaMask**

1. Custom RPC
2. Network Id - development / Ganache
3. New RPC Url - http://127.0.0.1:7545
4. Chain Id - 1337

**Chrome**

npm run dev

Url - http://localhost:3000

**Measure Taken**

- successfully imported local blockhain account as MetaMask account using Priavte Key of imported account
- installed ganache-cli

  ```
  npm install -g ganache-cli
  ganache-cli --chainId  //As per github docs


  Accounts     ----*/*/*/*/*/----
  Private Keys ----*/*/*/*/*/----
  Listening on 127.0.0.1:8545
  ```
- used port no 8545
- used chainId  1

still got no results as expected.. if required I will send the whole project file..